# To find a faster algorithm

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have some difficulties to find the best option to create two functions.

I have a variable:

```
BYTE bPattern[256];
```

Each byte can have a value of either 0 or 1 or 2.
Now, I need to create a function that will give the ID (or a signature) for every possible situation in this pattern.

```
void fGetIDFromPattern(BYTE bInPattern[], DWORD *pdwOutID);
```

Of course, I can create 2 `for` loops and to check all situations from first to last and to compare with `bInPattern`, but it will take too much time every time.
**Is there a way to do this faster and better?**

And.. also I need a second function...

```
void fGetPatternFromID(DWORD dwInID, BYTE bOutPattern[]);
```

Of course, instead of this "dynamic" method, I could create a static file with all possible values:

```
0 0 0 0 .. 0
1 0 0 0 .. 0
2 0 0 0 .. 0
0 1 0 0 .. 0
...
2 2 2 2 .. 2
```

Comment: There are 3^256 different patterns. You need at least 406 bits to describe each uniquely. If you're willing to spend 512 bits on the signature, you can simply bundle four elements into one byte: `output[i] = input[i/4] + 4 * input[i/4 + 1] + 16 * input[i/4 + 2] + 64 * input[i/4 + 3]`

Comment: Number of pattern and order to match with base 3 decimal.However, in this case the pattern is too many(3^256).

Comment: Are all the different combinations equiprobable? If not, you could perhaps use Hoffman encoding to reduce the key size for the most common pattern (but the least one will have to be larger than the optimal uncompressed size - 512bits).

Comment: need size : log 2 3^256 = 256 * (lon10 3)/(log10 2) = 405.75.. `406bits`.

Comment: What's the point of a void function where you pass in a `DWORD *` for output? Especially on 64 bit the pointer is even larger than the parameter. Why not `DWORD fGetIDFromPattern(BYTE bInPattern[])` or even better `unsigned getIDFromPattern(char inPattern[])` without all the unreadable Windows API style crud.

Comment: 1. Do you have any special requiements how the ID should look like? 2. "*I have some difficulties*" - what difficulties? What you attempted to implement?

Comment: @sjdowling The way I read it, the output is much larger than 64 bits, so the `pdwOutId` argument is a pointer to a `DWORD` array.   Although that second  function prototype needs to be changed to take an array.  To answer the OP's question, if you are willing to use 512 bits for an ID, then the answer is trivial.  For each byte in the pattern, encode each byte as two bits: `0` as `00`, `1` as `01`, and `2` as `10`.